# Dignified Shiva Pose Question

Tags: shiva

I know little to nothing about Hinduism. So, please be gracious to me. I was just joking once and did the Dignified Shiva (statue) pose. I notice, however, that there is little to no information on it on the Internet, at least as far as nuanced descriptions go. Can any of you explain briefly, based on text, if there's anything to doing it? Based on the religion, are there any effects (again please pardon me) to doing it? Or if you know of no answer to the question, I'm fine with that answer as well.

https://images.freeart.com/comp/art-print/fa18714034/lord-shiva-in-serene-pose.jpg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Dignified Shiva (statue) pose ... is it possible for you to attach an image depicting the pose ?

Comment: Added it. It's really similar to a Buddhist pose...

Comment: This pose is when a god gives a boon.